# Is there a way to apply a coding style per-file in a JetBrains IDE?

Tags: pycharm, clion, jetbrains-ide, editorconfig

I am working on a project that is transitioning to a new coding style.  The rule being applied is that old files should stay with the old conventions, but any new code written in new files should follow the new convention.

Using `.editorconfig` I can see how to do this per-directory.  But I still cannot find a way to do this per-file.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try specifying the exact file names in a section names (where you normally write file extensions), e.g. `[{package.json,.travis.yml}]` from https://editorconfig.org/#example-file. But making a Code Style (formatting rules) it per file -- it's going to be a real pain to maintain ... and is it really needed?

Comment: *"I can see how to do this per-directory. But I still cannot find a way to do this per-file. Is there a way to do this?"* Specify your file names in section names (as stated in the previous my comment). In theory that should work (depends how the IDE handles it; never tried this though)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editorconfig.html)

> IntelliJ IDEA allows you to manage all code style settings for each individual set of files

That being said, you can control the style per folder, not per individual file.

> .editorconfig file in the root directory containing the files whose code style you want to define.

and then

> All options from the .editorconfig file are applied to the directory where it resides as well as all of its sub-directories on top of the current project code style.

**TL;DR**

It's not possible to do what you want.